Unable to see drone, scene in Gazebo Harmonic
I have installed Ardupilot-ROS2 SITL with gazebo harmonic, and I have followed the instructions as mentioned.
When I finally test
ros2 launch ardupilot_gz_bringup iris_runway.launch.py
Gazebo just shows blue screen

and in RVIZ I can see my drone

I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with ROS2 humble and Gazebo Harmonic, have reinstalled it twice and I'm seeing the same error. Can someone please assist me in understanding the problem?

It may be a rendering issue with the Gazebo model on your system, or possibly the path to the model resources has not been set correctly. To help isolate the issue it would help to take a step back and run one of the simpler examples from https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot_gazebo that does not depend on ROS 2.
You should be able to run the gz sim -v4 -r iris_runway.sdf example without connecting to ArduPilot SITL and verify the copter is sitting on the runway.
Can you also included the log outputs from the launch as these may have details about issues with loading models and plugins in your session.
